# USB SATA adapter apparently not recognized

Tags: hard-drive, sata, sata-to-usb

I purchased a new laptop and a SATA USB Adapter and tried to connect the internal disk of my old computer to my new laptop in order to save my data.

My hard disk is [Western Digital WD5000BEVT 500GB](http://www.amazon.de/Western-Digital-WD5000BEVT-Scorpio-Festplatte/dp/B001JSSDGU/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1413222397&sr=8-1&keywords=wd%20scorpio%20blue) and I also have a [Lindy USB to SATA/IDE adapter](http://www.amazon.de/Lindy-SATA-Drive-Adapter-Speicher-%20Controller/dp/B0012E42Y8/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1413222457&sr=8-2&keywords=lindy%20sata%20adapter).

After connecting all components my computer can not recognize the hard disk

Things I have tried:

1. To buy a new hard disk (the same as before) - to ensure the damaged hard disk is not the reason
2. To buy a new adapter LogiLink-AU0006D-SATA-Adapter to ensure the adapter is not the reason
3. Try on Ubuntu and Windows XP - to ensure the System is not the reason.

But still nowhere any hard disk is recognized even by BIOS. I am not sure what is happened.

Comment: How did you verify it in ubuntu? It could possibly not be mounted

Comment: It says you've tried different operating systems, but were those on different computers also?

Comment: In this situation, you should also test the [power adapter and 4-pin white molex](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61TW%2B1%2Bzl7L._SL1500_.jpg). Can you also read of the power details from the power brick? I'm specifically interested in the amps.

Comment: @EricF thank you for your response. I just plugin USB of the adapter after Ubuntu 14 is booted.

Comment: Are you plugging the USB SATA directly into the new laptop, or to a USB HUB? If USB HUB, connect directly. Also, try different USB ports on the laptop.

Comment: hi @sunk818 the details on my power adapter is  Model: SPP34-12.0/5.0-2000  Eingang(Input):100-240V   INPUT  50-69Hz 1A  AUSGANG(Output) 12.0V 2000mA  OUTPUT 5.0V 2000mA  what is amp?

Comment: Years ago, some generic USB/SATA IDE adapters would ship with 1.0 AMP power adapters which failed to work on some models of hard drives. Your power adapter is 2.0 AMP (or 2000 milliamps) so that rules the power adapter issue. Is your hard drive working on the original computer if you plug it in directly in the motherboard?

Comment: @sunk818 thank you that's really professional. In order to connect SATA drive directly to USB port on laptop, it seems that a SATA-USB cable is needed which I do not have now. I connect through USB-adapter(HUB) all the time

Comment: Since you have a 2.5" HDD that can be powered from the 5V of the USB port, you could use a USB-SATA adapter designed specifically only for 2.5" drives.  These connect to both the SATA and power of the HDD, and are much easier to use.

Comment: I have a similar USB-SATA adapter for IDE and SATA.  Be sure you make connections in the proper order. See http://superuser.com/questions/408930/cant-mount-old-ide-hdd-using-an-usb-adapter/409482#409482

Comment: You should not use a USB HUB. You should connect the USB to SATA/IDE adapter directly to the laptop. If you do not have the USB to SATA/IDE now, you will have to get your replacement. Good luck.

Comment: don't you have other models of hard drive to try with? you seriously saying that you try different models of hard drives, different usb-sata adaptors, different computers, different OSs, and it never gets recognized?! forget the BIOS for now. Just looks for disk recognition within your OS

Comment: @sunk818 thanks for your suggestion. I have brought a USB/SATA cable now. This cable itself is recognized by the OS but not the the SATA hard disk with it. I can not open the things in my old hard disk. What could I probably do in the next step