# Why is my old PATA drive freezing my laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, freeze, pata

Well, I've been trying to ressurect my father's old external HDD and after investigating a little, I might have found what the problem is but, being lvl 0 in hardward, your advice would be much appreciated.

Anyway, long story short:

- The box in question is a ~ 15 yo STOREX Mobi disk FHD 354, which worked well on my good'ol Windows XP a solid 10 years ago and hasn't been kicked, dropped or even opened to my knowing
- HDD appears on drives list when turning it on
- ... but causes my computer to freeze when trying to access it. Laptop resumes right away and with no issue when I unplug or turn the HDD off
- No clicking sounds to report
- Windows' chkdsk and sfc yielded no results, just seem to be stuck forever
- Drive inside the box is a Samsung HD300LD ... with PATA connectors?!
- I'm using the right power cable so ... powerage is correct, maybe?
- The PATA data cable is separated in 5 smaller bands, which I guess might not be a good sign
- The "jumper" is empty and does not have a ... pin plastic thingy to set it to slave (I don't even know if it's actually mandatory)

And here is [a pic of the opened box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM8h1.jpg), which might sum it all even better.
My old tower computer doesn't seem to have a PATA connector and, not being an expert, I'd rather not start Frankenstein-ing my way out of here.

So.

Am I right in thinking the PATA data cable is ruined? If so, and since the alim seems functional, would buying an unbroken cable suffice? Should I buy a PATA to USB adapter?

Can I leave the jumper as is or do I need to explictly set it to slave?

In hoping I didn't forget anything. Looking forward to reading your answers!

Comment: "Am I right in thinking the PATA data cable is simply ruined?" No, it is ok to split the cable that way. Leave jumper as is  and try a pata to usb adapter after removing the hard drive.....https://www.amazon.com/AGPtek-Drive-Adapter-Converter-External/dp/B00BIE996S

Comment: *" but caused my computer to freeze when trying to access it"* -- Could be the drive in a recovery mode, i.e. continually trying to re-read a bad sector.  *"Powerage is correct"* -- What does that mean?  Also see https://superuser.com/questions/408930/cant-mount-old-ide-hdd-using-an-usb-adapter/409482#409482

Comment: Thanks for your answers! @Moab Good to hear the cable is fine, I'll go and try to grab a pata to usb adapter on Saturday, keep you posted.

@ sawdust I'll investigate about this recovery mode, thanks for the hint. What I meant by powerage being correct is that I made sure I'm using the right power cords, so power related issues are out of the way.

Comment: Simply *"using the right power cords"* is not sufficient to determine *"powerage is correct"*.  Correct power normally means that the power source has been *measured* (e.g. with a voltmeter/multimeter) to deliver the proper voltages.  Your assumption that all *"power related issues are out of the way"* is probably premature since you haven't actually measured anything.

Answer (score 0):

A few more things you could try:

1. Wait long when you start up Windows; the problematic part may time out if you wait long enough.
2. You can try some Linux distro if you have it; you have better control over when it tries to access hard disks, so you can make it boot no matter what (if you know how to set this up).
3. Once you get some OS to boot, try to see if it supports SMART values. That will tell you if the drive is still healthy.
4. Yes, if the adapter is broken, but not the harddisk, a USB-to-PATA adapter will do the job instead. Make sure you get one with an external power supply.