# Internal HDD connected to laptop via USB adapter is not recognized

Tags: hard-drive, sata, sata-to-usb

I have bought SATA to USB adapter (same as [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/114187967384) one) to connect my Seagate Barracuda 3.5'' 1Tb internal HDD (same as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LNJBA2I) one) to laptop that runs Windows 10.
I'm connecting adapter to HDD and to laptop, connecting power cable to adapter - and I can see both LED indicators glowing and I even hear that HDD starts working.
But there is no reaction in Windows.
Neither indication that HDD is connected (checked file explorer, device manager and disk management) nor error indication is shown.
I've also plugged adapter to different laptop's USB slots, with the same result.

What may be a cause of this issue?

Just in case I'm attaching screenshot of adapter's info here:
[image]

Comment: Is the HDD definitely good? Have you tried another HDD? If yes to both, *return the nonworking device.*

Comment: @Gantendo, **No** -- look at the picture, and read the question: the user *has* an external power supply.

Comment: I have found good luck using an actual enclosure for the 3.5" drives.  In fact.. they have all worked 100%.  I use a straight USB->SATA adapter for my 2.5" drives.

Comment: Pay attention to order of connections.  See https://superuser.com/questions/408930/cant-mount-old-ide-hdd-using-an-usb-adapter/409482#409482