# Why does my USB to IDE / SATA bridge only work on old PCs?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, bridge

I have an old USB2.0 to IDE / SATA bridge that I like to use for my loose HDDs, but on my newer PCs they always make problems.
The access to the HDD is slow or fails completely with an USB error.
The older PCs where I have no problems with do not have an USB3.0 controller, so I think this is part of the problem.

PC1 (with Problems): Intel Comet Lake / B460 / Windows 10 - Disconnects or has an "E/A was repeated" in the eventviewer.
USB2 ports behave similar.

PC2 (with Problems): Intel Haswell / H87 / Windows 10 - Disconnects after few minutes

PC3 (no Problems): Intel Kentsfield / G41 / earlier Windows 7, now Linux 5.4.0 Kernel

Linux identifies it as

lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 152d:2338 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JM20337 Hi-Speed USB to SATA
```

dmesg:

```
[56488.631468] usb 1-2.4: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[56488.765156] usb 1-2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2338, bcdDevice= 1.00
[56488.765159] usb 1-2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[56488.765161] usb 1-2.4: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
[56488.765163] usb 1-2.4: Manufacturer: JMicron
[56488.765165] usb 1-2.4: SerialNumber: ###
[56488.766083] usb-storage 1-2.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[56488.767208] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-2.4:1.0
```

Does this mean I have to buy a new bridge for the newer PCs or can this be fixed?

Comment: What USB chipset do the two computers have that are failing, what USB chipset does the adapter have, [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Are you performing the proper power-up sequence?  See https://superuser.com/questions/408930/cant-mount-old-ide-hdd-using-an-usb-adapter/409482#409482

Comment: "an old USB2.0 to IDE / SATA bridge "- what exactly is this device? How do you get the power to HDD?