How to read files off of a Windows 95 FAT32 hard drive on a modern Windows or Linux machine?
I have an old hard drive that I think used to be the main hard drive of a Windows desktop. I am looking for a old Excel document, and I think it may be on this drive.
I am looking for any way available to me to get access to the files on this drive. I am generally handy with Windows and Linux, but I don't delve into the details of storage devices very often. As far as available OSes that I have at my disposal, I have fedora, arch, and debian, win10, win11, and am comfortable installing just about any other OS I need, and any tool I need onto my linux devices. I also have a semi-torn-apart Dell Optiplex 5050 at my disposal that I can plug the HD into. I also have a Sabrent HDD-to-USB dock that I can use.
cfdisk shows that the partition type of the drive is "W95 FAT32", and has a label dos.
The drive does show up in Thunar when I plug it in via the dock, although it won't open.
When I try sudo mount /dev/sda1 ./dirname, I get an error stating:

"wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error."

I get the same error when I use the -t vfat argument as well.
I have also tried plugging the drive into the Dell OptiPlex tower I have, both via the usb dock and directly to the SATA cable (I think. I am not really sure if that is the right word.). In both cases, the boot loader did not seem to recognize that it was even plugged in. I had a different drive that has a boot partition on it and when I connect it, the boot loader does recognize its existence and allows me to add it as a boot option.
It could be that I have the tower set up for UEFI rather than "Legacy", although the toggle to switch to "Legacy" is greyed out.

Never hurts to review the drive's SMART data and run the short or even the extended tests.

Assuming that this old "main hard drive of a Windows desktop" has a 3.5" form factor, you need to make sure that you're supplying enough power to this drive. A SATA/molex power connector from a PSU is ideal. A USB connection would work best with a dual-voltage external power supply for the drive. Older and/or larger-capacity drives tend to require more power (in terms of current).

Follow the proper power-up sequence: https://superuser.com/questions/408930/cant-mount-old-ide-hdd-using-an-usb-adapter/409482#409482

It sounds like this not just an old drive, but an old drive - one that has sat unused for quite some time.
In such cases, it's likely the drive has suffered some bitrot (or data degradation over time). The bits that have been stored on the disk have slowly demagnetized, or the similar idea for a flash disk. (There used to be a little capacitor between gates that held charge in older flash technologies; I'm not sure what the current state of the art is.)
At any rate, when the OS tries to read the disk, it's not seeing the organized information it expects to see — it sees the "bad superblock" as reported.
This generally means that you're into data recovery territory, and caution is advisable.
The first thing I'd personally do: Image the disk/partition non-destructively, and then leave the disk alone in case you decide to send it back to professionals (for professional prices).
To do that, you'd need a second disk with at least as much space as the first. You don't need to partition/format anything (which is good!)
So, assuming the old partition is /dev/sda1, I would use the following command:
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/path/to/image/file.img bs=4m conv=noerror,sync status=progress


if=input file
of=output file
bs=block size; 4m seems reasonable
conv=noerror,sync: (noerror) Tell dd to continue operation, ignoring all read errors, (sync) Add input blocks with zeroes if there were any read errors, so data offsets stay in sync.  It's making lemonade when life gives us lemons.
status=progress: Because humans want to know 'are we there yet'

When that's done — you can take that image — and then duplicate it. Always keep a read-only, pristine copy of the dd image. Expect to ruin a couple of clones of the disk image — that way you only have to run the dd operation once. Then operate on a read-write clone. Clones are for experimenting on.
Now you can work with the clone as if it's a filesystem.

fsck it: fsck.vfat -n /path/to/disk.img.clone (I put in the check without changing option - but you can put in -a to auto repair, or other options).
mount it mount -o loop /path/to/disk.img.clone /mnt/old_disk.
And otherwise read/write it like it's a normal filesystem. If something doesn't work quite right, that's why you cloned the image before mounting it, right?


Good advice about not trying to work on the original HD.

I'd suggest gnu ddrescue for imaging, its designed for this and has a somewhat nicer syntax than classic dd
